# EntityFramework 4.1 dbContext.CreateQuery(Expression)

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Is it possible to create a `Linq` query using only following tools?

1 . Some `dbContext` instance

2 . An `Expression` which is passed from outside of `Class`.

Maybe my `Expression` includes joins or complex `Linq` queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly sure what you are trying to achive, but you can try snippet below:

```
public ObjectQuery<T> CreateQuery<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr) {
    ObjectContext octx = (ctx as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
    ObjectSet<T> os = octx.CreateObjectSet<Post>(); 
    ObjectQuery<T> q2 = os.Where(expr);
    return q2;
}
```

Comment: What if for complex expressions? like when I have some joins in expression?

Comment: The `DbContext` already has `ctx.Set<T>().Where(Expression)` , but I'm looking for something like [IQueryProvider.CreateQuery Method (Expression)](http://preview.library.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549139(v=vs.90).aspx) but for `DbContext` not `IQueryProvider`.

Comment: can you give some more details on how you are going to use it, if you have it. cuz i think either you or me miss something here

Comment: It doesnt matter how complicated your expression is. you can still pass it to `Where` method.

Comment: Also "Linq query" is executed by means of IQueryProvider, that is another point of confusion

Comment: `from c in customers
 join o in orders on c.ID equals o.ID
 select new { c.Name, o.Product };`